# Strange .NET 4.5 version-specific garbage collection issue with arrays

Tags: arrays, .net-4.0, garbage-collection, .net-4.5, memory-profiling

In my project, I have strange bug in my unit tests, which happens only when I use **.NET 4.5, but not when 4.0**.
[Here](https://interop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/29989) is source code of my project. [Here](http://sdrv.ms/1b5aIeB) is compiled binaries.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download source code and compiled binaries
2. Place unzipped Binary folder in Interop\Main\ folder.
3. **Run Interop.Core.Tests.NETFX45 unit tests**

Test **IsAliveAfterCollectionWork** must fail. If you attach memory profiler (I use free **dotMemory 4.0 EAP** with settings Profile .NET process -> Collection every N-th object: 1, Memory traffic: Collect and Use profiler API), you will see, that array **MarkedObject[]** has not been collected, although nothing **has no references to it**.

My configuraton:

- Windows 8.1
- .NET Framework 4.5.1
- I use Visual Studio 2012, but 2010 and 2013 installed too

Comment: Can you describe your problem in a way that doesn't require downloading anything?

Comment: No, I can't, because I don't know even WHY it happens...

Comment: Can you tell us what does the test do? Can you post just the relevant source code? What conditions indicate failure? Why does it matter that the test fail?

Comment: Test must guarantee correct work of my "weak" collection. Code is too large. See Interop.Core.Tests/GarbageCollection/WeakReferencesStorage, Interop.Core.Tests/GarbageCollection/Helpers/EnumerableExtension, Interop.Core/GarbageCollection/WeakReferencesStorage, Interop.Core/GarbageCollection/WeakReference and Interop.Core/GarbageCollection/SafeGCHandle files in your browser. It's only one condition: test fail when I use .NET 4.5 assembly and pass when I use .NET 4.0 assembly.

Comment: You may need to change the gc model to look more like 4.0, given the gc changes for 4.5 you may need to rethink your tests

Comment: All GC changes in .NET 4.5 are optional, except server background collection.

Comment: What happens if you force a 2nd gen GC?